# JsonMergePath update based on timestamp

Tags: java, json, timestamp

I am trying to update JSON data based on incoming data. For that purpose, I am using JsonMergePatch to update the existing key elements of the nested JSON object. The attribute updates are happening correctly as per the data available.

```
JsonNode oldData = some JsonNode data
JsonNode newData = some JsonNode data
JsonMergePatch patchstep = JsonMergePatch.fromJson(newData );
JsonNode mergedNode = mergePatch.apply(oldData);
```

Where we are facing issues is when there is data which has timestamp fields which may not be in order. For example, existing data

> { "eventAttribute1" : "sample2", "eventDt":"2022-03-22T12:00:00" }

new data

> { "eventAttribute1" : "sample1", "eventDt":"2022-03-22T11:59:00" }

When I merge using JsonMergePatch, it updates the data with newer timestamp with older timestamp as well. Is there a way in JsonMergePatch I can update based on a timestamp field? If not possible is there an alternate way to dynamically update JSON based on a timestamp field?

Thank you!